# Is there a way to tell how many of an item I've bought?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

I'm trying to get a Golden Shovel/Axe, and I buy Fertilizer and Saplings from the T&T store every day. I'm starting to wonder how long this is going to take :(